# Toggling a navbar on/off in mobile. Error: Cannot read parentnode of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I'm trying to make my mobile navbar full screen when in mobile. The Hamburger button works as expected when clicked. I see all the links full page, when I click on a link it disappears and I it takes me to the section of the page. The problem is that it only works once. If I do two consecutive clicks I get `Cannot read property parentNode of undefined`. I know that the problem is in the way I'm hiding my `ul` element. When I click the first time I change to `display: none` ( initial value was `visible`) and I have to wait until is again available in the `DOM` to be able to hide it again.

I'm trying to figure out how to best solve this issue. Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/intercoder/pen/d8268d331d6eca0078a1dd91c129cf78/?editors=0110)

Thanks.

**jade**

```
// BEM terminology added, but not yet implemented. Just basic css down there 

nav.desktop
  ul
    li
      a(href="") Home
    li
      a(href="") About
    li
      a(href="") Labs
    li
      a(href="") Contact 

nav.mobile
  .hamburger
    button.hamburger__btn Toggle
    span.hamburger__top
    span.hamburger__middle
    span.hamburger__bottom
  ul.navigation--mobile--hidden
    li
      a(href="") Home
    li
      a(href="#about") About
    li
      a(href="#labs") Labs
    li
      a(href="#contact") Contact
main
  section#about
    h1 About
    p  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dolorum, accusamus officiis possimus cupiditate facere, sequi illum nobis saepe quidem repudiandae magnam natus cum animi repellendus. Illum qui, nobis voluptas.
  section#labs
    h1 Labs
    p  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dolorum, accusamus officiis possimus cupiditate facere, sequi illum nobis saepe quidem repudiandae magnam natus cum animi repellendus. Illum qui, nobis voluptas.
  section#contact
    h1 Contact
    p  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dolorum, accusamus officiis possimus cupiditate facere, sequi illum nobis saepe quidem repudiandae magnam natus cum animi repellendus. Illum qui, nobis voluptas.
```

```
/// Variables
/// Colors
$gray: hsla(0, 0%, 88.6%, 1);
$red: hsla(300, 47%, 80%, 1); // plum
$green: hsla(150.5, 47.3%, 74.7%, 1);
$yellow: hsla(60, 47.3%, 74.7%, 1);
$white: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);

/// Sizes
$breakpoint-mobile: 30rem !default; // or 
$breakpoint-tablet-portrait: 76.8rem !default;
$breakpoint-tablet-landscape: 102.4rem !default;
$breakpoint-laptop: 1024px !default;
//$breakpoint-laptop: 113rem !default;


/// Breakpoints
@media only screen and (min-width: $breakpoint-mobile) {
  /* Use for testing only */
  nav.mobile {
    //display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@media (max-width: $breakpoint-mobile) {
  nav.desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}

/// Base
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body,
html {
  background: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  color: $white;
}

;
.navigation--mobile--hidden {
  display: none;
}

.navigation--mobile--flex {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: $white;
  list-style: none;

  li {
    border: 1px solid $green;
    //flex-basis: height / 4;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    //flex-basis: 10%;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $red;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: color 300ms;
    display: block;
    &:hover {
      color: $green;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  }
}

// Content
nav.mobile {
  > div.hamburger {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    min-width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background: $white;
    text-align: center;
    /*@include small-screen($small-screen) {  [ERROR]: mixin not working
    nav.mobile {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  } */
    > button {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    > span:nth-of-type(1) {
      width: 75%;
      height: 20%;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
      background-color: $red;
      margin-top: 5px;
      animation: squishTop 3s ease infinite;
      @include animate (squishTop) {
        from {
          transform: scaleY('');
        }
        to {
          transform: scaleY(1.5);
        }
      }
    }
    > span:nth-of-type(2) {
      width: 75%;
      height: 10%;
      background-color: $green;
      animation: squishMiddle 3s ease infinite;
      @include animate(squishMiddle) {
        from {
          transform: scale3d('');
        }
        to {
          transform: scale3d(1, 0.5, 0);
        }
      }
    }
    > span:nth-of-type(3) {
      width: 75%;
      height: 20%;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      background-color: $red;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      animation: squishBottom 3s ease infinite;
    }
  }
}

nav.desktop {
  min-width: 100vw;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $red;
  ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: $white;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $red;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: color 500ms;
    &:hover {
      color: $green;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  }
}

/// Main
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

/// Section
section {
  border: 1px solid $red;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.animate {
   animation: zoomOut 3s;
}

/// Keyframes
///  Hamburger Menu
@keyframes squishTop {
  from {
    transform: scaleY('');
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleY(1.5);
  }
}

@keyframes squishMiddle {
  from {
    transform: scale3d('');
  }
  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 0.5, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes squishBottom {
  from {
    transform: scaleY('');
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleY(1.5);
  }
}

/// Navbar - after click
@keyframes zoomOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```
$(function () {
  var hamburgerBtn =  document.getElementsByClassName('hamburger__btn')[0];
  var navBar = hamburgerBtn.parentNode.parentNode;
  var navBarUlEl = navBar.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

  // Makes the hamburger btn clickable
  hamburgerBtn.onclick = function() {
    toggleClass(navBarUlEl);

     var ulNavFlex = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation--mobile--flex')[0];
    var navBarFlex = ulNavFlex.parentNode;

    console.log('This is the ulnavflex: ' + ulNavFlex);
    console.log('This is the navflex: ' + navBarFlex.classList);
    console.log('This is the navbar: ' + navBar.classList);

    var ulNavFlexLinks = ulNavFlex.getElementsByTagName('a');

    console.log(ulNavFlexLinks);
    console.log(ulNavFlex)


    for (var i = 0; i < ulNavFlexLinks.length; i++) {
      //console.log(ulNavFlexLinks[i]);
      toggleLinkClick(ulNavFlexLinks[i]);
    }
}

  // Toggles Link Clicks
  var toggleLinkClick = function (el) {
    el.onclick = function() {
      console.log('I was clicked from: ' + el)
        if ( navBarUlEl.classList == 'navigation--mobile--flex' ) {
          navBarUlEl.classList.add('animate');
          navBarUlEl.classList.remove('navigation--mobile--flex');
          navBarUlEl.classList.add('navigation--mobile--hidden');
        }
      console.log(navBarUlEl.classList);
      }
    //return navBarUlEl;
  }

  // Sets the nav visible again

  // Toggles between desktop/mobile navigation
  var toggleClass = function(el) {
    switch (el.className) {
      case 'navigation--mobile--hidden':
        return el.className = 'navigation--mobile--flex';
        break;
      case 'navigation--mobile-flex':
        return el.className = 'navigation--mobile--hidden';
        break;
      default:
        return el.className = 'navigation--mobile--hidden';
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: WHY are people jusing this much jQuery for making a mobile menu? DO IT IN CSS, and if you need to switch classes and such, do add that via js, but it should really not be needed at all. You can do the animation in CSS, you can do the show/hide in CSS - there really is no reason to use any js at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is a logical error . When you select a section from the menu you add two classes `animate` and `navigation--mobile--hidden` in your `toggleLinkClick` listener . So when you click the menu again `toggleClass` get called where the switch case fails since you have `animate navigation--mobile--hidden` in `el.className` and class is not updated to `navigation--mobile--flex` , modify the `toggleClass` function as below

```
 var toggleClass = function(el) {
    if ($(el).hasClass('navigation--mobile--hidden')) {
      el.className = 'navigation--mobile--flex';
    } else if ($(el).hasClass('navigation--mobile-flex')) {
      el.className = 'navigation--mobile--hidden';
    } else {
      el.className = 'navigation--mobile--hidden';
    }

  }
```

*Note: I have used jquery to check the element has the class, since you have used jquery*

Or another way to fix this is to remove the `animate` class as soon as the animation is done in your `toggleLinkClick` listener , as below :

```
 var toggleLinkClick = function(el) {
    el.onclick = function() {
        console.log('I was clicked from: ' + el)
        if (navBarUlEl.classList == 'navigation--mobile--flex') {
          navBarUlEl.classList.add('animate');
          navBarUlEl.classList.remove('navigation--mobile--flex');
          navBarUlEl.classList.add('navigation--mobile--hidden');
          navBarUlEl.classList.remove('animate');
        }
        console.log(navBarUlEl.classList);
      }
      //return navBarUlEl;
  }
```

In the above case , you don't have to change your `toggleClass` function to use `if`

Here is the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/vikneshwar/pen/Jbyvda) with second solution.
And [Codepen](http://codepen.io/vikneshwar/pen/ObjZvR) for the first one